# Dijkstra algorithm Java - find shorthest path

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I need to implement Dijsktra algorithm in my case:
From A to B time to reach destination is 5.
From A via C to B time to reach destination is 3. (from A to C (1) , from C to B (2) => its 3.

i try it below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // mark all the vertices 
        Vertex A = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex B = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex C = new Vertex("C");


        // set the edges and weight
      A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 5) };
      C.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A, 1) };
      B.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(C, 2) };


        computePaths(A); // run Dijkstra
        System.out.println("Distance to " + B + ": " + B.minDistance);
        List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(B);
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    }
```

http://pastebin.com/jGynb3t8
Whats do i wrong? I need to find the shorthest Path to B.

Comment: Have you attempted to implement `getShortestPathTo()` yourself? If so, what have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: On first sight, the code seems fine. Try debugging your code and see where it deviates from your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You make the mistake with your edge class. In this part of `computePaths`

```
// Visit each edge exiting u
for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
{
    Vertex v = e.target;
```

you assume that the edge always points **along** your shortest path. But for the edge `e` between `A` and `C`, it holds that `e.target == A`, since you created it as

```
C.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(A, 1) };
```

You should change the line in `computePaths` to

```
Vertex v = (e.source == u ? e.target : e.source);
```